# Laravel collection changing key issue

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I foundout that my collection were with the wrong keys, so I started debuging the code. Doing that I noticed that if I pass more than 2500 items in the array to the collection it loses their keys, otherwise, if I pass less than 2501 items it stays normal

**Limiting to 2500 items**

```
    public function getProdutos($codigoconcentrador, $codigoempresa, $pluck)
    {
        $model_produtos = new Produto();

        $query = $model_produtos->newQuery();

        $query->where('codigoconcentrador', $codigoconcentrador)
            ->where('codigoempresa', $codigoempresa)
            ->where('status', 'A');

        $query->limit(2500);

        dd($query->pluck('nomeproduto', 'codigopro'));

        if ($pluck) {
            return $query->pluck('nomeproduto', 'codigopro');
        } else {
            return $query->get();
        }
    }
```

*Result*

```
Collection {#260 ▼
  #items: array:2500 [▼
    1 => "CIMENTO VOTORAN CP II Z 32 - 50 KG"
    7 => "SOPA 250G - LEGUMES"
    8 => "SOPA 250G - CARNE"
    9 => "CIMENTO CIPLAN CP II Z 32 - 50 KG"
    10 => "ARGAMASSA VOTORAN ACI"
    11 => "ARGAMASSA VOTORAN ACII"
    13 => "ARGAMASSA COLA BEM ACI "
    14 => "ARGAMASSA COLA BEM ACII "
    ...
    ...
```

**Without the limitation**

```
    public function getProdutos($codigoconcentrador, $codigoempresa, $pluck)
    {
        $model_produtos = new Produto();

        $query = $model_produtos->newQuery();

        $query->where('codigoconcentrador', $codigoconcentrador)
            ->where('codigoempresa', $codigoempresa)
            ->where('status', 'A');

//        $query->limit(2500);

        dd($query->pluck('nomeproduto', 'codigopro'));

        if ($pluck) {
            return $query->pluck('nomeproduto', 'codigopro');
        } else {
            return $query->get();
        }
    }
```

*Result*

```
Collection {#3809 ▼
  #items: array:2875 [▼
    0 => "CIMENTO VOTORAN CP II Z 32 - 50 KG"
    1 => "SOPA 250G - LEGUMES"
    2 => "SOPA 250G - CARNE"
    3 => "CIMENTO CIPLAN CP II Z 32 - 50 KG"
    4 => "ARGAMASSA VOTORAN ACI"
    5 => "ARGAMASSA VOTORAN ACII"
    6 => "ARGAMASSA COLA BEM ACI "
    7 => "ARGAMASSA COLA BEM ACII "
    8 => "REATOR 2 X 40 BIVOLT"
    9 => "CHA VERDE SOLUVEL - LIMAO 200G - UND"
    10 => "ROLDANA P/ POCO GANCHO 12CM. R.C.A."
    ...
    ...
```

**UPDATE**

the function is receiving the second parameter `$query->pluck('nomeproduto', 'codigopro')`, so I debugged the pluck function, just when it becomes an collection it loses the key

**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php**

```
public function pluck($value, $key = null)
    {
        dd(Arr::pluck($this->items, $value, $key)); // First Result
        dd(new static(Arr::pluck($this->items, $value, $key))); // Second Result
//        return new static(Arr::pluck($this->items, $value, $key));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plug` method search for a column with that name and uses it as the new key for each element... If you want just to take two columns of each element then you can use `$collection->only('aa', 'bb')`. Besides that, for many reasons you should be working with pagination... An array of 2500+ elements is crazy.

Comment: I need it to be the key cause is a select input, and I know that is crazy kkkkk, I'm working on a input that while the user write it searchs for the products with ajax, but I think that even being crazy, it shouldn't lose the key, right?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the first result when you pass a key as the second parameter:

```
pluck('nomeproduto', 'codigopro')
```

And you're getting the second one when you do not pass it:

```
pluck('nomeproduto')
```

So, double check the code.

Comment: `$query .= $query->limit(2500);` ??

Comment: no, the function is receiving the second parameter, so I debugged the pluck function, just when it becomes an collection it loses the key.

**First Result:** `Arr::pluck($this->items, $value, $key);`
**Second Result:** `new static(Arr::pluck($this->items, $value, $key));`